# How to set header and Footer position in poi word (XWPF)?

Tags: apache-poi

I want to set header and footer's position. Header from top: 45.4 pt, Footer from bottom: 28.4 pt as we can see in Header & Footer Tools menu when we open a word file. Thanks in advance! [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this you will need setting the page margins. For this you will need `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPageMar`. And for using this we need the fully `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` as mentioned in https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025.

Example:

```java
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPageMar;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordHeaderFooterTopBottom {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  // create header-footer
  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
  if (headerFooterPolicy == null) headerFooterPolicy = document.createHeaderFooterPolicy();

  // create header start
  XWPFHeader header = headerFooterPolicy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Header");

  // create footer start
  XWPFFooter footer = headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Footer");

  CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr();
  if (sectPr == null) sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.getPgMar();
  if (pageMar == null) pageMar = sectPr.addNewPgMar();
  pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(720)); //720 TWentieths of an Inch Point (Twips) = 720/20 = 36 pt = 36/72 = 0.5"
  pageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(720));
  pageMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(1440)); //1440 Twips = 1440/20 = 72 pt = 72/72 = 1"
  pageMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(1440));

  pageMar.setHeader(BigInteger.valueOf(908)); //45.4 pt * 20 = 908 = 45.4 pt header from top
  pageMar.setFooter(BigInteger.valueOf(568)); //28.4 pt * 20 = 568 = 28.4 pt footer from bottom

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordHeaderFooterTopBottom.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Note the special measurement unit `Twip` = **TW**entieths of an **I**nch **P**oint.