# How to put a table inside header of word using java apache poi?

Tags: java, ms-word, header, apache-poi

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun paragraphOneRunOne = paragraph.createRun();
int twipsPerInch =  1500;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
table.setWidth(5*1800);
XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0); 
tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText(CUSTOMER_NAME);
tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText(displayName);
tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText(CUSTOMER_ID);                  
tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText(displayCustomerID);               
XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();                                               
tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText(AGE_GENDER);
tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText(displayCustomerAge);
tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText(VISIT_DATE);
tableRowTwo.getCell(3).setText(formatedDate);
XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.createRow();                                             
tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText(REFERRED_BY);
tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText(displayRefBy);
paragraphOneRunOne.addCarriageReturn();
paragraphOneRunOne.setText("Patient Report");
paragraphOneRunOne.setBold(true);
paragraphOneRunOne.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE);
paragraphOneRunOne.setFontSize(18);
    //paragraphOneRunOne.setColor(255,0,0);
paragraphOneRunOne.setFontFamily("Times New Roman");
paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
paragraphOneRunOne.addBreak();
paragraphOneRunOne.addCarriageReturn();
```

Now can you Explain me where to modify my table and how to put it in the header. i tried the previous answers. but it's not working for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572996/how-to-add-a-table-to-header-or-footer/39578388#39578388

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the current `apache poi 5.0.0` `XWPFHeaderFooter` provides a method [XWPFHeaderFooter.createTable](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFHeaderFooter.html#createTable-int-int-). So one can put the table directly into the header.

Your code snippet provided as [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show how to do:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;

public class CreateWordTableInHeader {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run;
  XWPFTable table;
  XWPFTableRow row;

   //the header
  XWPFHeader header = document.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
  
  table = header.createTable(3, 4);
  table.setWidth("100%");
  row = table.getRow(0); 
  row.getCell(0).setText("CUSTOMER_NAME");
  row.getCell(1).setText("displayName");
  row.getCell(2).setText("CUSTOMER_ID");                  
  row.getCell(3).setText("displayCustomerID");  
  
  row = table.getRow(1);                                               
  row.getCell(0).setText("AGE_GENDER");
  row.getCell(1).setText("displayCustomerAge");
  row.getCell(2).setText("VISIT_DATE");
  row.getCell(3).setText("formatedDate");
  
  row = table.getRow(2);                                             
  row.getCell(0).setText("REFERRED_BY");
  row.getCell(1).setText("displayRefBy");
  
  paragraph = header.createParagraph();
 
  //the body
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Patient Report");
  run.setBold(true);
  run.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE);
  run.setFontSize(18);
  run.setFontFamily("Times New Roman");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTableInHeader.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: How to set header and Footer position in poi word (XWPF). I saw you answered this question before. I tried this with the above code. but it's not working. It shows some problems with CTPageMar. Help me with this, please.

Comment: @Hareesh: Are you referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43252994/how-to-set-header-and-footer-position-in-poi-word-xwpf/43269396#43269396? This works for me also using current `apache poi 5.0.0`. Please note the reference to https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025. For `apache poi 5.0.0` you will need `poi-ooxml-full jar`, else some of he `CT...` classes will not be in class path.

Comment: Yes. I saw that I cannot find CTPageMar.

Comment: @Hareesh: https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025

Comment: I need to increase the Header from Top about 5cm. Any other options than this CTPageMar

Comment: @Hareesh: No, there is no way around `CTPageMar`. But this class is in `ooxml-schemas-*.jar` for `apache poi` up to version `4` and in `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar` for `apache poi 5.0.0`. So there is no problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232995/discussion-between-hareesh-and-axel-richter).